# Cohomology of affine hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, affine-schemes, etale-cohomology

I'm interested in calculating cohomology of a smooth affine hypersurface (over an arbitrary field). I know I can use (algebraic) de Rham cohomology, which is "easy" in the complex case, but even there I'm finding the computations a bit messy for, say, polynomials with many variables. Any advice for me? Thanks!